# How can I read vectors from text files to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have 20 text files each containing a vector of size 180. How can I access each text file and assign the vector to a variable?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it manually use `Import Data` under `File` (or use `uiimport`).
If you want to automate it use `fid = fopen(filename)` and then use `var = textscan(fid, 'format')` where format depends on how your vectors are structured. Spend some time reading `doc textscan` and `doc fopen` everything you probably need to know is in those two files. If your data is nicely structured look at `doc importdata`.